# Error: trying to redefine a primary key as non-primary key

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, python-dataset

I'm using the [dataset](https://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to attempt to back up a postgres database into an sqlite file. The code I'm running goes as follows:

```
local_db = "sqlite:///backup_file.db"

with dataset.connect(local_db) as save_to:
    with dataset.connect(postgres_db) as download_from:

        for row in download_from['outlook']:
            save_to['outlook'].insert(row)
```

If I print one row of the table, it looks like this:

```
OrderedDict([
    ('id', 4400),
    ('first_sighting', '2014-08-31'),
    ('route', None),
    ('sighted_by', None),
    ('date', None)
])
```

However, when I get to the line `save_to['outlook'].insert(row)` I get an error with the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/Development/Python/TTC/backup_db.py", line 25, in <module>
    save_to['outlook'].insert(dict(row))
  File "/home/anton/.virtualenvs/flexity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataset/table.py", line 79, in insert
    row = self._sync_columns(row, ensure, types=types)
  File "/home/anton/.virtualenvs/flexity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataset/table.py", line 278, in _sync_columns
    self._sync_table(sync_columns)
  File "/home/anton/.virtualenvs/flexity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataset/table.py", line 245, in _sync_table
    self._table.append_column(column)
  File "/home/anton/.virtualenvs/flexity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 681, in append_column
    column._set_parent_with_dispatch(self)
  File "/home/anton/.virtualenvs/flexity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 431, in _set_parent_with_dispatch
    self._set_parent(parent)
  File "/home/anton/.virtualenvs/flexity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 1344, in _set_parent
    self.key, table.fullname))
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Trying to redefine primary-key column 'id' as a non-primary-key column on table 'outlook'
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? I've tried this in python 2.7.14 and 3.6.3

Comment: does it fail on second insert ?

Comment: What is a "non primary key"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! So, the trick is that by default the `database` library makes tables with an auto-incrementing integer primary-key. But, my data already has an 'id' column. In order to avoid this problem, I should define my table before I try to add lines to it, and define it with no primary key as follows:

```
with dataset.connect(local_db) as save_to:
    with dataset.connect(postgres_db) as download_from:

        table_to_save_to = save_to.create_table('outlook', primary_id=False)

        for row in download_from['outlook']:
            table_to_save_to.insert(row)
```

By doing `.create_table(table_name, primary_key=False)` I can make sure that i can insert my own id values into the table.

I found this solution by [reading the docs](http://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=primary%20key).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a schema and table made for "outlook", did you make a PK field? Did you let sqlite decide which field to make a PK field?

It is highly that you are trying to insert id twice. Once, sqlite is inserting itself, and other comes from the other table records.

Comment: This makes sense. I'm not defining a schema - that is supposed to be taken care of by the library - but it could be that the library just doesn't think I would have an 'id' field in my data.